# Building a snake out of UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Imagine a static snake game, i.e. where the snake cannot move, but only increase or decrease in size. I currently try to accomplish this with as many UIImageViews as there are "snake parts" and one UIImage (representing one "snake part") which I assign to all the UIImageViews. Decreasing and increasing the snake should result in new "snake parts" moving in to or out of the screen. The problem that I ran into is that it seems that I cannot change the position of an UIImageView once it is set. That made me question the whole idea of my solution. Therefore I have two questions to you:

1. is it true that I cannot change the position of an UIImageView once it is set?
2. are there other and/or "better" ways of accomplishing the concept above?

Comment: 1. The position of a `UIImageView` _can_ be modified at any time.  2. It depends.  But any solution will involve computing where images whether contained in layers or image views will be on screen.

Comment: @NSBum Thanks for your reply! I just realized that I was trying to call setBounds on the view, instead of setFrame, which seems to do the job of repositioning the view. But what is the preferred method according to you, layers or image views?

Comment: If you're intending to use animation to enliven the changes in the snake, then layers/Core Animation would be preferred.  Another answerer mentioned SpriteKit if your deployment target OS supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were targeting iOS 7 for your game, I would recommend taking a look at SpriteKit, which is a framework better suited for doing 2D game graphics. For older iOS versions, you probably want to use CoreAnimation and CoreGraphics instead of UIKit. UIKit is more of a user interface building framework where as the other two are for building animations and 2D graphics.

To actually answer your question, yes, you can set the position of the UIImageView multiple times and it will move to the new position. Just set the `center` property of your UIImageView. You probably want to use a different framework to achieve your graphics though. I would take a look at CoreAnimation and SpriteKit. There are some really good WWDC session videos on them.

Comment: I think I've been a little unclear about what I'm doing. It's not really a game I'm making, but I used the game analogy trying to illustrate my problem. I will go on using UIImageViews now that I manage to reposition them (with your help). CoreGraphics, SpriteKit and other mentioned libraries are interesting and I will keep them in my head for future needs. Thank you all for helping me out on this one!

Comment: No problem, in that case it sounds like doing this in UIKit (setting the position of the UIImageView like Arbitur suggests) is perfectly reasonable. You should also look at UIView animations and CoreAnimation to see what's available to you there.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you are just adding the imageViews and then try to move them. You should add them in an array also and when you want to move them you do this:

```
UIImageView *imgView = imgArray[index];
imgView.center = CGPointMake(100,100);
```